# Entity Types aren't marked virtual in existing project

Tags: c#, entity-framework, moq

I'm trying to mock (using Moq) DbSet's in the DbContext in an existing project that I think was upgraded from VS 2012. I'm getting an error and it's because those DbSet<>'s aren't marked as virtual so they can't be mocked. When I look at newer projects I've done they are marked as virtual.

Since this is in the .edmx file I can't just add virtual to the code since it's autogenerated. Does anyone know any properties that I can set to make them virtual?

Comment: Which version of EF are you using?

Comment: It's EF version 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In EF6, by default, `DBSet` members are created as `virtual`. This cannot be changed from configuration, but T4 template (`.tt` file) must be edited. Most likely someone edited it before and removed the `virtual` keyword.

To find your T4 template, expand the tree created by `.edmx` file in Solution Explorer. You will find a `.tt` file in it.

To make your `DBSet`s `virtual` again, you need to find a method `string DbSet(EntitySet entitySet)` (in default `.tt`, it is line 307). This method create a property declaration and you can manipulate its pattern here. By default,

```
"{0} virtual DbSet<{1}> {2} {{ get; set; }}"
```

is used. Find your version of this pattern and change it to your liking (or simply a default version I provided).

EDIT: If you cannot find this method easily, try searching for

> DbSet<

EDIT: After editing and saving `.tt` file, it should be executed automatically. If not, try right-clicking it and selecting 'Run Custom Tool'.